# Office 365 - send document to Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, office365

I'm using Docusign for office 365. I have a document library with documents that needs to be signed. If the user use the Docusign ribbon everything is working fine - including the login with office account.

I want to develop a web application that will take the document based on user's name and sent to the Docusign with one click only. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to start is to go here: www.docusign.com/devcenter and take a look at the API.